# C#:Check for root node

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I`m reading everynode from the below xml, while reading is there a way we can check if selected node is Root node? Here "Root" may change to something else.

```
<Root>
  <I a="" b="">
     <E c="" d=""/>
     <E c="" d=""/>
  </I>
</Root>
```

What i`m doing is below ->

```
public string some_name1(string xmlDoc)
        {
            XmlDocument I_xDoc = new XmlDocument();

            I_xDoc.LoadXml(xmlDoc);
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            a.Append("{ ");
            some_name(a, I_xDoc.DocumentElement, true);
            a.Append("}");
            return a.ToString();
        }

private static void some_name(StringBuilder strBuild, XmlElement Xmlnode)
{ How to find root here with parameter  Xmlnode}
```

Please help.

Comment: How do you _read_ the XML? Show us some code.

Comment: Are you using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

Root node of xml is return by `DocumentElement` property of `XmlDoc`

```
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
```

Comment: xmlDoc.DocumentElement i`m passing to a function, and there the parameter is of XmlElement.

Comment: Could not get you what u wanna say here ..

Comment: Rajeev: Please check for revised post.